# Duplicating field elements and position of duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code base:

http://jsfiddle.net/XpAk5/47/

The JS I use when the button is clicked is here.  I have it append to #advTrains.  This works fine in the position played (#kpPositions).  Doesn't make sense when I look at it why the code would behave differently.

```
$('#addTraining').click(function(){
    //increment the value of our counter
    $('#kpAdvancedTrain').val(Number($('#kpAdvancedTrain').val()) + 1);
    //clone the first .item element
    var newItem = $('div.advtrain').first().clone();
    //recursively set our id, name, and for attributes properly
    childRecursive(newItem, 
        // Remember, the recursive function expects to be able to pass in
        // one parameter, the element.
        function(e){
            setCloneAttr(e, $('#kpAdvancedTrain').val());
    });
    // Clear the values recursively
    childRecursive(newItem, 
        function(e){
            clearCloneValues(e);
    });
    // Finally, add the new div.item to the end
    newItem.appendTo($('#advTrains'));
});
```

The elements and IDs are incrementing correctly, however I can't for the life of me figure out why when I click the "add position" the added box appears above the button (as I want), but when I click the "add advanced training" it appears below the box.  I want the "add advanced training to also appear above the button.

I'm sure it's something quite simple, but I've been looking at this code for quite some time and can't come up with the reason why this is happening.

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing comment tag:

```
<!--.controls-->
```

To help spot it, running a quick Tidy in the fiddle reformatted to this:

```
<!-- Advanced training code begin -->
<div id="advTrains">
    <input type="hidden" id="kpAdvancedTrain" name="kpAdvancedTrain" value="0" />
    <div class="advtrain" id="advtrain">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="item-0-name">Advanced Training</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="kpAdvancedTrain_0" id="kpAdvancedTrain_0" class="input-large" />
            </div>
            <!--.controls>
            </div><!-- .control-group-->
        </div>
        <!-- .advtrain -->
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your HTML: there is a comment you forget to close, so one of the closing div tags is commented out. Close that comment and your elements will be added in the appropriate place.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="item-0-name">Advanced Training</label>
    <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" name="kpAdvancedTrain_0" id="kpAdvancedTrain_0" class="input-large">
    </div>
    <!--.controls> --> <!-- this comment wasn't closed -->
    </div><!-- .control-group-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found your error: You forgot to close your last div tag.

```
    <!-- Advanced training code begin -->    
<div id="advTrains">
    <input type="hidden" id="kpAdvancedTrain" name="kpAdvancedTrain" value="0">
        <div class="advtrain" id="advtrain">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="item-0-name">Advanced Training</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="kpAdvancedTrain_0" id="kpAdvancedTrain_0" class="input-large">
                    </div> <!--.controls>
            </div><!-- .control-group-->
        </div><!-- .advtrain -->   
</div><!-- #advTrains -->
</div> <!----NEED TO CLOSE LAST DIV ------>
```

EDIT: Actually, you forgot to close your  comment. It is keeping one of your divs commented out (which is why adding the extra div fixed it. You need to close it like this:

```
<!-- .controls -->
```